# dynamic binding Jquery callback function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sure i am over thinking this...

File A has an empty container div, button is clicked, loads data into that div...

File A has  button that i want to bind a function to from the jquery return above.

AJAX FILE

```
echo json_encode(array('callback' => 'javascriptFunction'));
```

"javascriptFunction" is a valid function that can be called. How or can i bind that function.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "../ajax.php",
    data: '&m=loadExternalData&f='+ module,
    success: function(resultData) {
        $('#externalFieldsetTitle').html(resultData.title);
        $('#externalSaveButton').bind('click', function() {
            resultData.callback;
        });
    }
});
```

I am passing back more than just "callback", but for this example i dont think it is needed.

Basically i load external modules into a div and want to allow them to specify their save function and pass it in so the core save button will work on the multiple external loaded files. I believe that makes sense?

Comment: The .live() method usually works for me when im trying to work with any dynamically created content. So try the .live() method instead of the .bind()

Comment: @Ian - Tried that, no difference. Thanks.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: What is your question? What is not working for you? Any errors?

Comment: @David - No errors, it just does not call the "javascriptFunction" function, which is basically just an alert for testing.

Comment: You can log the `resultData.callback` and make sure it’s a function. Perhaps you need to `eval` it or something.

Comment: @Batman, .on .bind .live all have the same result... nothing.

Comment: @David - Tried jQuery.globalEval on the callback as well...

Comment: @AustinBest can you please post how the `resultData.callback` is formatted?

Comment: @AustinBest, just pointing it out. In your case, the button itself is not dynamically loaded so the .bind() should work anyway. What do you get if you `console.log(resultData)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#externalSaveButton').bind('click', function() {
            window[resultData.callback]();
        });
```

Or directly:

```
$('#externalSaveButton').bind('click', window[resultData.callback]);
```

(in this case it must be in global scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#externalSaveButton').live('click', function(resultData) {
            resultData.callback;
        });
});
```

Comment: try this, i think about that sry

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request probably returns a string as function. What you can do is try to pass it as a `Function` constructor:

```
var callback = new Function(resultData.callback);
$('#externalSaveButton').bind('click', callback);
```

But it all depends on how the `resultData.callback` is formatted.

Comment: Tried this, didn't do anything either. Thanks.